# JDBC give MySQL datetime in UTC

Tags: mysql, jdbc, timezone

My Java:

```
Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(timestamp);
Timestamp dbTimestamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());       
insertTimestampPreparedStatement.setTimestamp(3, dbTimestamp);
```

PhpMyAdmin/MySQL always displays this in my local time, even when I do

```
insertTimestampPreparedStatement.setTimestamp(3, dbTimestamp, Calendar.instance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

I'm not sure if MySQL stores them aware of timezone, and the only way I checked this was updating a timezone row to NOW() directly in phpmyadmin, and it then showed me a time in GMT.  So either there is a bug in phpmyadmin/mysql or my code is not sending over timestamps in the correct timezone.

How do I get this to work in UTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JDBC driver **must** use the local timezone when retrieving or storing timestamps, unless a Calendar with the specific timezone is provided.

Unfortunately, the JDBC spec isn't always clear on how drivers should behave, and it looks like MySQL does it wrong. For MySQL you can force the timezone it uses by specifying one or more options in the connection string `serverTimeZone` and related properties. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html for a full list.

Comment: "*must use the local timezone*": unless the timestamp is stored **with** a timezone I assume? (not relevant for MySQL though)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If the database has timezone information, then the driver should use that when retrieving, on storing it should still default to the local timezone.