# JDBC SQL Time zone

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm using Spring with apache commons BasicDataSource.

The time zone shows as GMT via:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

My input is in epoch time, 1386831420000 and 1386833220000, so the query should be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE AND arrival_time BETWEEN '2013-12-12 06:57:00' AND '2013-12-12 07:27:00';
```

I enabled SQL profiing, and this is the query that actually gets executed, so I don't get the correct results:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE AND arrival_time BETWEEN '2013-12-12 01:57:00' AND '2013-12-12 02:27:00';
```

Notice that the times are off by 5 hours, since I am EST-5, and the time should be in GMT.

**My question is: How can I tell MySQL or Spring JDBC not to use the client time zone, and simply to always use GMT?**

Please comment if there is any detail I could add to solve the issue.

Comment: What is the time zone of the Java client?

Comment: The Java client is in EST.

Comment: A JDBC driver is required to default to the local timezone, see my answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522055/jdbc-give-mysql-datetime-in-utc/10561994#10561994

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly converting the date string into a date type using `TO_DATE` (or implementation specific date converter function)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE arrival_time BETWEEN 
TO_DATE('2013-12-12 06:57:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
AND 
TO_DATE('2013-12-12 07:27:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

The above example is in Oracle SQL but the principle of explicitly casting a date string to a date type is common throughout SQL implementations.

Comment: I already have the dates as Java Calendars, not strings. Those have the correct time and time zone.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the JDBC driver isn't properly detecting Mysql's time zone setting. You may need to specify the server's time zone in the connection string. Try adding

```
serverTimezone=UTC&useTimezone=true
```

to the connection string. For more information, refer to the JDBC doc at http://cs.wellesley.edu/~cs304/jdbc/connector-j.html#connector-j-reference